# Google Maps API for Codeigniter, add location to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I want to allow users to pick their location using google maps. For example they would type in their zipcode and press enter. Afterwards I want to add the country and city where they are located in the database.

Is this functionality easy to develop? I'm looking for some guidance please.

Comment: you should try http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how it's quite easy. I'm not going to write it for you but you probably best start with looking how **(reverse) geocoding** in google maps works.

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html (check the geocoding examples)
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/
- http://www.timshowers.com/2008/08/php-geocoding-tutorial-with-the-google-maps-api-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

all the guidance you need already exist in documentations for these 2 products:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at : http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/this-is-how-you-use-the-google-maps-api/ and search for Google Maps in the CodeIgniter wiki : http://codeigniter.com/wiki/